# Wake up from standby/hibernate programmatically in Windows in python?

Tags: python, windows

I'm thinking of making an alarm clock that can wake up some systems (depending on motherboard model) from hibernation/standby modes at a certain pre-determined time. I've seen similar software do this, I think in VB. I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere on how to do this in Python. Does anyone have any hints? If it's not possible in Python, is there perhaps a way to do it in e.g. c++ and call that binary from python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SetWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686289.aspx) can wake up a suspended machine.

Comment: The CreateWaitabletime and SetWaitableTimer win32 functions can even be accessed from the win32event module included with pywin32: http://pywin32.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pywin32/pywin32/win32/test/test_win32event.py?revision=1.3&view=markup